# "4 year long" or "4 yearlong"?

Tags: hyphenation, measuring-units

I am wanting to convey this sentence:

> This year marks the end of the 4 year long 'Environmental Protection Victoria' project.

I have looked online to no avail, can anyone tell me if '4 year long' in this context is grammatically correct? Or if an alternate such as '4 year-long' or '4 yearlong' is better? The sites I've checked online all refer to yearlong (singular), but I'm wondering if the spelling is different when we're talking about multiple years. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please see *[Hyphenating measurements](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208040)* and the earlier *[Pluralization rule for “five-year-old children”, “20 pound note”, “10 mile run”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366)*.

Comment: Also the "hyphenation" section of Wikipedia's page on [compound modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier).

Comment: (in a nutshell, the preferred solution is: "... the 4-year-long 'Environmental Protection Victoria' project."; some would also recommend spelling out the number, so "four-year-long".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pluralization rule for "five-year-old children", "20 pound note", "10 mile run"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1366/pluralization-rule-for-five-year-old-children-20-pound-note-10-mile-run)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answers and comments should be binned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it would be "4 year-long." If the sentence was along the lines of "The 'Environmental Protection Victoria' project was four years long," it wouldn't be hyphenated.