# Is 'a 210-million-people market' correctly written?

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compounds, compound-adjectives

Usually I find compound adjectives quite straightforward, but I'm not so sure when it comes to the following:

A 210-million-people market

So how should I refer to a market 210 million people large with a compound adjective before the noun?

Comment: Maybe *a market with a 210-million-demographic*.

Comment: No. A market with a 210-million demographic.

Comment: Hyphens are customary and usual. Inverted commas - no. Do not give personal opinions as advice.

Comment: @Jeep, "No. A market with a 210-million demographic", but a 210-million-demographic market.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyphenation in compound adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39273/hyphenation-in-compound-adjectives) (this is the one with the most relevant title, but this subject has been done to death.) eg [hyphenating measurements](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208040/hyphenating-measurements/208069#208069) ... 'a hundred-meter race, a 250-page book, a fifty-year project, a three-inch-high statuette, it's three inches high,'.

Comment: @Edwin: Agree with you.

Comment: It’s fine. In this style of writing, where a noun like *market* is modified by a preceding adjective like *210-million-people*, what matters most is the simple declarative style. There’s no harm in linking the nouns with hyphens, as in:  “The supply was unlimited. The buyers were not. It was a pour-it-down-their-throats-till-they-can’t-take-it-anymore kind of market, and the Jack Company planned its sales campaign accordingly.”

Answer (score 3):

Although “a 210-million-people market” follows the rules of punctuation, as Phil Sweet and Araucaria pointed out, grammatically it should be “a 210-million-person” market. I suggest making it “a market of 210 million people,” which is easier to read and say.

Comment: I would support the second one; in inverted commas, and without hyphens.

Comment: Technically “a market of 210 million people”  is correct. Too. But I'm not sure that 'technically' means much.

Comment: I meant that it follows the rules of punctuation, so it's not wrong. I guess I should have said that instead of "technically." Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks it needs to be *person*, not *people*? Like 20 Mule Team Borax.